# What happens when a person dies without fulfilling their greatest desire(s)?

Tags: moksha, death, rebirth, desire

If a person dies whether intentionally , naturally or accidentally without fulfilling their deepest desire. Whether it be sexual/materialistic/spiritualistic, what happens to their Atman after death? Are they condemned to roam the earth until their desires are fulfilled ?

Comment: re-birth or in extreme cases, negative entities with attachment and anger.

Comment: No, fulfillment is not necessary.

Comment: all beings take endless births (and deaths) until all their desires are satisfied and debts are cleared. by definition, that's the purpose of birth.